# AWS Quicksight - Enabling User Comments

Tags: amazon-web-services, dashboard, amazon-quicksight

How would functionality for user comments on a dashboard be built? For example, if an issue is flagged I would like to let the user comment if they have further details/explanation of the issue. I would also like to save the comments and pull them historically.

Have seen this in a QS dash before, but I can't find any documentation on how you would go about building the framework for this.

Comment: Some time has passed since you asked this question, I wonder if you found a solution for it? Leaving a comment on a graph is a much needed functionality!

Answer (score 0):

QuickSight doesn't appear to support this functionality within QuickSight. Likely what you saw was QuickSight dashboard embedded into a page that happened to have a separate, unrelated user comment box. If you do find something where someone is commenting directly on a QuickSight dashboard, I would be thrilled to see it!!